# Youtube iFrame Disabled by Header Element in Different Div Container

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a div container containing several iFrame youtube videos. Below this, I have a different div container, and I've noticed that the h2 element in that different div container is disabling all the iFrame Youtube videos in the previous container from being responsive (playable).

The youtube videos must be in column containers with border-box box-sizing.

CodePen Link (since Stack Overflow is not loading in the iFrames) https://codepen.io/they102/pen/oVgRVM

```css
.container {

  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

.row {

  margin: 0 -5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;


}

.column {

  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;

}

.iFrameCard {

  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.iFrameCard iframe {

  display: block;
}

.iFrameLabel {

  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.iFrameLabel h3 {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
    <div class="iFrameCard">

     <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lLWEXRAnQd0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     
    </div>


   </div>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="iFrameCard">

     <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lLWEXRAnQd0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">

  <h2><b><i><u>H Element Disabler</u></i></b></h2>
 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of each `.container` div, you are floating `.column`, and that `float` needs be cleared. By not clearing, the `float` is essentially collapsing the clickable area of the parent to *nothing*. The easiest fix is to add the following one line:

```css
.container {
  …
  clear: left;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give float:left or display:inline-block; to  .container class.

```
.container {

  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display:inline-block;

}

or

.container {

  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
 float:left;

}
```